# VSCode personnal shortcuts not working in notebook editor

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, keyboard-shortcuts, vscode-snippets

I added a shortcut in vscode to insert a small pattern in my code:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+alt+z",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "args": {
        "snippet": "#ZZZ ${1:comment}"
    }
}
```

This shortcut perfectly works in **all "normal" files** but I want to use it in a **jupyter notebook** (*.ipynb). I therefore opened it in VSCode and it is now read in **Notebook mode** (which is fine as I want to execute it). The shortcut then doesn't work. Any clue?

I checked, it isn't used in *Default keybindings*.

**Version of VSCode** 1.40.2

Comment: Related to the snippets issue: [How do I use snippets for Jupyter Notebook with VSCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59220447/2745495)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use user snippets in the Jupyter extension (yet), as a workaround you can however use interactive python, it offers almost a similar experience.

When you write `# %%` in a normal `.py` file this is like opening a new Jupyter cell.
You can convert a Jupyter notebook into a python file and it will use interactive python. There you will be able to use your snippets.